# Using variables when defining aliases in bashrc

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to reuse alias variables while defining other aliases in `.bashrc` file as shown below:

```
alias cwd='cd /work/local/assignment1'
alias module1='$(cwd)/module1'
```

Where `module1` is a directory I want to `cd` into.

This does not work and I would like to know whether it is possible to use variables while defining aliases.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is module1 a directory that you want to cd into?  Or is it a command that you want to run?

Comment: module1 is a directory i want to cd into

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `cwd` is not a `variable` but an `alias`.  You could instead do:

```
cwd='cd /work/local/assignment1'
alias module1='$cwd/module1'
```

As suggested by @StephenHarris, you may want to add the following to get your `cwd` working as usual:

```
alias cwd='$cwd'
```

Comment: Also add `alias cwd='$cwd'` for completeness.